# The mysterious mansion

Tags: riddle

You're in a mansion, the power is out, and the main entrance is blocked.

In the mansion there are 3 doors that are coloured blue, green, and red.

You enter the red one. This time it leaves to another three doors of the same colours.

You enter through the green one. It then leads to another 3 doors that are the same colours.

You enter the blue one. Now there are 5 doors and a sign.

The sign says ‘If you survive and make it to the right door you can leave.’

- The first door says “if you open me poison gas will come out.”
- The second door says “if you open me you will have to sit on an electric chair and pull the switch on.”
- The third door says “dangerous spiders will come out of me if you enter.”
- The fourth door says “the whole building will explode if you open me.”
- And the last door says “ if you open me an unlimited amount of water will come out of me and you will drown.”

Which door do you choose? You can ONLY choose 1.

Hint: read top to bottom. ;)

Comment: Maybe. But that user has not logged on in a long time, and no answer has been accepted for that question.(Besides, it is poorly formatted.)

Comment: I just heard that riddle from a friend so decided to write it down lol.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would:

> Go into the room with the electric chair because there is no power.

Comment: Nice one, you win

Answer (score 5):

I would exit through

> The blue door I just came through

Comment: Can’t turn back XD

Answer (score 5):

Fifth and the third doors are close contendors, but I will go with the fifth

> **First door**, I can't take a risk as I can die of poison.
>  **Second door**, The chair can be battery operated. Or, once I sit, power might be back.
>  **Third door**, this can be an option if there were no better options. Spider's might be dangerous but can not be fatal.
>  **Fourth door**, No way, the explosion would defintely kill me
>  **Fifth door**, There is nothing called unlimitted amount of water. Definetly, the sign is a lie. This door is my best bet

Btw, if there is a power cut, how can you see the color of the doors?

Comment: Night vision lol

Comment: Or... It's daytime?

Answer (score 4):

> Electric chair all the way.

As the first line says,

> Power is out.

Comment: I just came and realised this, but looks like you beat me to it! Well done!

Comment: Congrats you win

Answer (score 2):

i'll

> open the second door that says “if you open me you will have to sit on an electric chair and pull the switch on.” Since, the *power is out*, no harm can happen to me.

Answer (score 1):

I would:

> open the door with water, then the door with the electric chair. The electricity will fail due to the water and I can pass through the door. Then I would be safe

Comment: Sorry but you can only choose one :)